# Write list of data frames to Excel in multiple sheets

Tags: r, excel

I have a data frame that I run a few analyses on and I want to export the results to Excel files. One workbook per group and each analysis results on a separate tab. I would prefer to use `openxlsx` for the exporting to take java out of the equation.

```
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(openxlsx)

df <- iris

# Analysis 1
results1 <- df %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise(count = n())

# Analysis 2
results2 <- df %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise(mean.sl = mean(Sepal.Length),
            mean.sw = mean(Sepal.Width))
```

My desired export output would be three Excel workbooks, `setosa.xlsx`, `versicolor.xlsx`, and `virginica.xlsx`; each with two sheets "results1" and "results2" containing only their within-group results. Meaning no setosa rows in the versicolor Excel file.

I tried to split `results1` and `results2` into lists of data frames in order to use `lappy` with `write.xlsx` but I'm not able to make it work.

```
r1_list <- dlply(results1, .(Species))
r2_list <- dlply(results2, .(Species))
```

Other suggestions?

Comment: My suggestion, unhelpful as it may be, is to not use Excel.

Comment: Also, I believe the [`xlsx` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xlsx/xlsx.pdf) is what you're looking for

Comment: `xlsx` depends on java, which I'm trying to avoid, if possible

Comment: The WriteXLS package worked fine for me. Just pass it a named list of data.frames and those will be tabs in the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sample code

```
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(openxlsx)


setwd("c:/r")
df <- iris

# Analysis 1
results1 <- df %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise(count = n())

# Analysis 2
results2 <- df %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise(mean.sl = mean(Sepal.Length),
            mean.sw = mean(Sepal.Width))

#get the unique species
sp <- unique(df$Species)

createSpreadsheets <- function(species,r1,r2){
  ## Create new workbooks
  wb <- createWorkbook() 

  ## Create the worksheets
  addWorksheet(wb, sheetName = "Results1" )
  addWorksheet(wb, sheetName = "Results2" )

  ## Write the data
  writeData(wb, "Results1", r1)
  writeData(wb, "Results2", r2)

  ## Save workbook to working directory 
  saveWorkbook(wb, file = paste(species,".xlsx", sep=""), overwrite = TRUE)
}

## create spreadsheets by calling our function for each species
for(s in sp){
  createSpreadsheets(s,results1[results1$Species==s,],results2[results2$Species==s,])
}
```